# como puedo contar lineas por metodo?

Tags: java

quisiera saber como contar lineas por metodo este es mi metodo pero quiero saber cuantas lineas tiene este metodo pero no se como si me pueden ayudar seria de mucha ayuda gracias

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Indicamos que fichero va a leer el programa, por lo que es un fichero 
  //por defecto.
  //En la vble siguiente definimos la ruta en la cual se encuentra el 
  //fichero
  String nombreFich = "../Program2/src/program2/Program2.java";
  String fullClassName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() 
  [1].getClassName();
  String className = fullClassName.substring(fullClassName.lastIndexOf(".") 
  + 1);

 //asignacion de archivo
 File fichero = new File(nombreFich);
 int intTotalMetodos = Program2.class.getDeclaredMethods().length;
 int intTotalMetodos2 = Program2.class.getDeclaredClasses().length;
 String sMethodName = new String (Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() 
 [1].getMethodName());

 String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() 
 [1].getMethodName();

 try {
    BufferedReader fich = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nombreFich));
    //Usamos la clase BufferReadeader para tener acceso a un metodo propio 
   (readLine()) y asi mediante un contador contar las lineas.
   int contadorL = 0;
   int contadorLO = 0;
   int total = 0;
   String linea = "";
    try {
      //En este caso la condicion final del while corresponde a null, para 
      //indicar el final de linea
    while((linea = fich.readLine()) != null){
       contadorLO++;
       linea = linea.trim();
        if ("".equals(linea) || linea.startsWith("//") || 
                            linea.startsWith("}") || linea.startsWith("/*") 
        || linea.startsWith("*/") || 
                            linea.startsWith("*")) {
            contadorL++;
        }
                     total = contadorLO-contadorL;
       }
     System.out.println("El número de líneas :" + total);

     System.out.println("Tiene: "+intTotalMetodos+" métodos\n");
    System.out.println("que paso papa: "+className+"\n");
    System.out.println("Este clase tiene: "+intTotalMetodos2+"\n");
      System.out.println("Este método se llama: "+methodName+"\n");
   }
  catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 } 
 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

 }

 }
```

Comment: Necesitas leer las lineas  que hay dentro del archivo??, por que la verdad no entiendo que quieres decir con lo de saber las lineas de tu método!!

Comment: Por favor, formatea el código, así es imposible leer.

Comment: Hola Fatima, te recomiendo que pases por el [tour] y trates de proporcionar mayor información a tu problema, que expliques lo que no te resulta y lo que intentaste. ¿Quieres contar las lineas de codigo en un archivo `.java` de forma programatica? ¿O solo las lineas de un metodo en particular? Lo primero es mas sencillo que lo segundo

Answer (score -1):

Si lo que necesitas es saber cuantas lineas de código tiene tu documento o fragmento, muchos editores de texto que tienen función de editor de código ya tienen lineas numeradas.

Un ejemplo seria el editor [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), el cual además tiene la función de seleccionando un fragmento de código, decirte cuantas lineas tienes seleccionadas.

[image: Editor_notepadd++]

Muchos otros tambien tienen esta función, (Eclipse, Netbeans, Android Studio...)

Comment: no creo que esto sea lo que pregunta. Te sugiero esperar a que aclare su pregunta.